# Whether to parse multiple statements at once or not

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4, grammar

I noticed that in the [`MySQLParser.g4`](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-workbench/blob/8.0/library/parsers/grammars/MySQLParser.g4) file that it only handles one statement at a time:

```
query:
    EOF
    | (simpleStatement | beginWork) (SEMICOLON_SYMBOL EOF? | EOF)
;

simpleStatement:
    // DDL
    alterStatement
    | createStatement
    ...
```

Why is this choice made instead of parsing the entire file or script, which may include multiple SQL statments, such as:

```
CREATE TABLE...;
INSERT INTO ...;
INSERT INTO ...;
# could be thousands of statements here
```

Is this for efficiency so that the parser only handles one statement at a time so that it doesn't have to consume as much memory? Or basically, why is the choice made in the parser here to only do one statement at a time, and if that's the case, how would it parse multiple statements at once, for example in MySQL Workbench if I have these two statements:

[image]

Finally, for testing purposes, is this a good way to add a convenience method for debugging in IntelliJ, or how would this normally be done if the grammar only expects one statement at a time, and you want to, for example, test to make sure all ten statements are correct?

```
root
    : EOF
    // this line is for testing only
    | selectStatement (SEMICOLON selectStatement)* (SEMICOLON EOF? | EOF)
    // this line is for the actual parser
    | selectStatement (SEMICOLON EOF? | EOF)
    ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several arguments pro single-statement processing:

- **Killer Reason:** Each statement can use a different delimiter (which you cannot handle in the parser grammar). Delimiters are not part of the SQL syntax.
- In editors you will want to know where a statement starts and ends, without first parsing the full text (think of megabytes sized dumps), e.g. for executing a single statement.
- You don't want to miss all following statement details, if only one statement contains a syntax error.
- Parsing a single statement at a time gives you much better response times (e.g. when editing SQL code while it's still being parsed).
- The server can process single statements only, anyway.

I implemented the statement handling in MySQL Workbench and did it the same way in [MySQL Shell for VS Code](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-shell-plugins/blob/master/gui/frontend/src/parsing/mysql/MySQLParsingServices.ts#L294). The statement splitter is usually very fast (100ms in C++ for a million statements, depending on the box it runs on). This allows to do a quick first run for the statement ranges, show the statement indicator and make the editor ready for statement requests (for execution). After that a background thread is used to parse the individual statements for errors, which can be stopped at any time when a statement was edited.

Comment: ` The statement splitter is usually very fast (100ms in C++ for a million statements` -- wow that's so cool, so you're splitting the statements before sending it to the antlr parser, correct? Are you able to share the Statement splitter you use?

Comment: also, if we assume the statement delimiter is always `;`, would it be simple enough to have a parser that removes comments, strings/quoting, and then just splits on semi-colon? Or would that still be missing things?

Comment: Yes, for the reasons mentioned above I always split the statements. The [C++ splitter](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-workbench/blob/8.0/modules/db.mysql.parser/src/mysql_parser_module.cpp#L2271) does not copy anything, just determines offsets, which is why it is so fast. And [here](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-workbench/blob/8.0/backend/wbpublic/sqlide/sql_editor_be.cpp#L790) is the code that does the processing (first splitting, then parsing).

Comment: About the delimiter question: actually, I listed more than the delimiter reason. But of course, if you limit the problem domain/feature set, then you can get away with a simpler solution. But experience shows that sooner or later it will bite you and you will have to add things that were never meant to be in the original code. So better think twice before you decide for the simpler solution. On the other hand you should never write code just in case you might need it in the future.

Comment: can't thank you enough, thank you! Statement splitter doesn't look too complicated either, a hundred plus lines or so and a few case statements -- thank you!

Answer (score 1):

<s>Whether to allow for multiple statements is pretty much just a grammar design choice.  Depending upon the context, it might have been more straightforward to know you'll only see a single statement at a time, or that you can easily separate multiple statements and send each to a parser.</s>

It does look like it would be useful for you.

A simpler version would be:

```
root : selectStatement? (SEMICOLON selectStatement)* SEMICOLON? EOF
```

you should always have an EOF

Another thing that doesn't always dawn on designers is that your grammar can have multiple start rules.  So you could also have a

```
selectStart: selectStatement SEMICOLO? EOF;
```

rule that only allows for a single statement and depending upon you situation you can choose which start rule to use.  I had a graphical tool for a language I wrote so sometimes I parsed `expr`s, sometimes `stmt`s and sometimes `script`s.  Each had its own start rule.  But don't forget to end a start rule with an `EOF`. This forces the parser to look at ALL of your input.  Without it, it will parse as much as it can, but will ignore training input that doesn't fit a parse rule.
(well, it's *possible* not to have EOF, IF you have a custom stream that remains open so there is no end of input.  However, this would not be the case in your situation.)

Comment: thanks for the feedback, and I agree that's much simpler/better than what I had. But what about the main/first question about why to have a single-statement root instead of multiple -- is that more for parsing speed and memory considerations?

Comment: added more to answer

Comment: Sorry, but it's not a grammar choice. SQL statements don't always use a semicolon as delimiter, for example check statements with embedded programs (events, procedures, functions).

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I didn’t realize that (though I probably should have known you had a better reason than arbitrary choice)